# Python pandas smart append

Tags: python, pandas

I have one csv file containing:

```
Car     Model   Color    Price
Proton  X70              100K
Honda           white    100K
```

And I have a dataframe:

```
Car       Color      Model
Perudua   White      Myvi
```

I wish to append the dataframe to the csv file but my code below won't give me the desired output, it will not append based on the column name.

```
if not os.path.isfile('C:/Users/sj/Desktop/car.csv'):
    CombineTable.to_csv('C:/Users/sj/Desktop/car.csv', header='column_names',index=False)
else:
    CombineTable.to_csv('C:/Users/sj/Desktop/car.csv', header=False, mode='a',index=False)
```

My desired output is:

```
Car     Model   Color    Price
Proton  X70              100K
Honda           white    100K
Perudua Myvi    White
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: what is the delimiter in your csv? I see some values are missing, how do you understand when a value is missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Car':['proton','honda'],'Model':['X70',''],'Color':['','White'],'Price':['100k','100k']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Car':['perudua'],'Model':['Myvi'],'Color':['White']})

pd.concat([df1,df2],sort=False).reset_index()
```

gives this output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you csv really looks like that given, then you need to import it using the `sep='\t'` tab separator:

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv',sep='\t')
```

then your csv output command works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Reading csv:

```
cars = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/sj/Desktop/car.csv')
```

Creating new DataFrame:

```
new_car = pd.DataFrame([['Perudua'], ['White'], ['Myvi']], index=['Car', 'Color', 'Model']).T
```

New df looks like this:

```
    Car     Color   Model
0   Perudua White   Myvi
```

Combining the two DataFrames:

```
cars.append(new_car, sort=False, ignore_index=True).sort_index()
```

Final result, looks like this:

```
    Car     Model   Color   Price
0   Proton  X70     NaN     100K
1   Honda   NaN     white   100K
2   Perudua Myvi    White   NaN
```

Notes:

- Adding ignore_index=True and `.sort_index()` at the end when combining, is so that you can have the index order as `0, 1, 2` etc...
- Adding `sort=False`, is to not get the error warning.

Feel free to experiment with removing each one, to see how the final result changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to load the table from your csv first, then concatenate it with your other dataframe. For this you can use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) function:

```
df_from_csv = pd.read_csv('path')
CombineTable = pd.concat((df_from_csv, second_df), axis = 0)
CombineTable.to_csv('path')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
df_csv = pd.DataFrame({'Car':['proton','honda'],'Model':['X70',''],'Color':['','White'],'Price':['100k','100k']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car':['perudua'],'Model':['Myvi'],'Color':['White']})

df_new = pd.concat([df_csv, df], sort=False).reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
df_new.to_csv('yourfile.csv')
```

Do what you asked:

```
       Car Model  Color Price
0   proton   X70         100k
1    honda        White  100k
2  perudua  Myvi  White   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code that will give your desired output:

```
import numpy as np
csvcar = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\car.csv')
dfcar = pd.DataFrame([['Perudua','White','Myvi']], columns =['Car', 'Color', 'Model'])
df = pd.concat((csvcar, dfcar), ignore_index=True)
df1 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

Output of above code is as below:

```
    Car     Color   Model   Price
0   proton          X70     100k
1   honda   White           100k
2   Perudua White   Myvi
```

Then you can export it or replace it with your csv files:

```
df1.to_csv('C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\car.csv')
```